# How to show $\exp_p\colon T_pM\rightarrow M$ is surjection?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

$(M,g)$ is a complete connected Riemmanian manifold respect to its metric. How to show $\exp_p\colon T_pM\rightarrow M$ is surjection ?

Maybe, it is likely Hopf-Rinow theorem.

Comment: This is essentially immediate from Hopf-Rinow... think about it.

Comment: Add "connected" in the question, otherwise the statement is false.